# Can you disable the sensor when using the Google DirectionsService to generate a route?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm using the following code to generate a route and I want to specify an explicit starting position but it always returns a route from my location provided by the location API rather than the location specified in the `origin` parameter. The location API has been granted access from a different part of the site, so simply disabling it is not an option.

```
var current_position= new google.maps.LatLng(...);
var request = {
    origin: current_position,
    destination: to,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
};

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsService.route(request, function(data, status) {
    //...
}
```

I thought about specifying `sensor=false` but `sensor` isn't a valid property of [the DirectionsRequest object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest).

How can I get the DirectionsService to honour the origin I specify?

Comment: It would help if you could share a little bit more of your code. How is your var `current_position` declared? If you look at [the doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests) you will see that the origin can either be a `LatLng` or a `String`, which you can determine yourself.

Comment: @pascal Updated, current_position is being set from a specific LatLng.

Comment: This should work. There are several examples at Google docs which use different origins and destination. Only difference is that they use string (address) and not latlng. Did you check variable `current_position` if it's correct?

Comment: As @AntoJurković says, this should work. Can you try to set the `current_position` to a city name (eg. London, UK) to check if there is not something else wrong in your code? Or better, if you have a fiddle to play around with?

Comment: this code should be good example: [animate marker directions](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html). It is using strings. I hardcoded the same start address as latlong and the result was the same.